# Stop application if application missing in server and deploy application on server

Tags: maven, maven-2, weblogic, pom.xml, weblogic12c

I am using Maven version 2.2.1  for deploying an application on Weblogic Server 12.1.1 .

I have written the pom.xml file and is deploying the application in the weblogic server.

Now if the application is missing in the server the stop app goal is getting failed.

So in my case, if the application is not present, it should skip the rest of the processes and deploy the the application onto the server.

Comment: That sounds not like a job or Maven. (Ant, Scripting, Puppet, Chef etc.).

Comment: Good question ! I didn't use Maven with weblogic, but I remember that I used Ant try/catch block if the app was not present ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maven tag 
    `<failOnError>`
can be used for this.